# Running R script using command line on Windows

Tags: r, batch-file, rscript

I'm trying for my first time to run an R script from command line on WINDOWS to automate calculation with another program. So I made my R script using R studio and saved it a .bat file with this line

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin CMD BATCH C:\my_directory\my_script.R
```

Then I putted the script and files the script have to be executed on in the same directory, the one that contains files to run also the program I need. I came throught command line in that  directory and I executed the batch file but it doesn't work. I have this as a error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin"it is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 an executable program or batch file.
```

Where I am wrong? thank you!

Comment: I have not installed __R__, but the help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window explains in last paragraph on last help page that a file name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must be enclosed in `"` to get all the characters inside the double quoted argument string interpreted literally. So I suppose, the right command line is: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\my_directory\my_script.R"`

Comment: To be more specific, you provided a directory as an internal or external command, instead of the executable file which lies within it, `R.exe`. The correct command is posted in the first comment above.

Comment: @Nancy now that you are actually using `r.exe` in your script, you should be getting a different error than before. We cant see your screen. You have to provide the error messages and debugging information. Saying it does not work does not help us help you.

Comment: Also the initial error message you posted does not match the code you posted. Based on your code the error would have been: `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: with double quote I have ""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"". Then I tried both with R.exe and Rscript.exe (after copying them in the Directory I'm interested in) and I have this error "Cannot find the specified path"

Comment: You shouldn't be copying the R software files to any folders.  They need to stay where they were installed to and executed from where they were installed to.

Comment: My R script is for running another program in my pc and manipulating file. Now, the other program I need has to be executed in his folder too so I copied R files in that folder

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Rscript` instead, assuming its in your `PATH`.
E.g.

```
Rscript C:\my_directory\my_script.R
```

Or a single expression

```
Rscript -e "print(123)"
```

Comment: trying as you suggested I have "Cannot find the specified path." also typing only "Rscript" so I suppose that the problem is with R

Comment: Then `Rscript` is not in your `PATH`, so you need to add it.

Comment: I added Rscript in the path, still the same. On linux when there is a file, it has to be executable. Is there something similar in windows? I'm not so experienced on windows

Comment: After you add `Rscript` to the path, in my case by adding the folder `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64` to the path, be sure to open and close CMD for `PATH` to refresh. Then open a new window of CMD, and type `Rscript`, and tell me your output.

Comment: Okay my mistake was coping only one file and not all contained in the folder. Now it works but doing  Rscript C:\my_directory\my_script.R a windon error from R appears with "installation problem"